# Low quality image rezise in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm developing this site:
http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/

If you visit it in Chrome images look good, in the header or in the slider.
[image: Tulpep]

But if you visit in Internet Explorer it looks this way:

[image]

Why?
The image is being resized in the HTML. If I dont want to change the images to don't resize, what should I do?

Comment: Aliasing problem also happens in Firefox. You probably want to consider using a scaled down image instead of high-res image here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers use different algorithms for image resizing. Some spend more CPU cycles and produce a "better" image, others do a quick'n'dirty cheap CPU-light scaling that results in a "worse" output. It's always a trade-off between quality and speed when it comes to image (sound, video, ...) processing and there's no universal rule on which approach to take.

150K for an image that's bigger than an average visitor's monitor is definitely an overkill. You are definitely better off having specific images for specific parts of your page. Or you may consider using vector graphics instead of bitmaps? Maybe even HTML5 canvas - that would more likely render more or less the same on different browsers (one would hope).

Comment: I definitely agree with YePhick here. You should look into using vector graphics here instead of bitmap graphics. This would allow the image to be resized without any change in the actual picture.

Comment: @thenewguy I am currently using png, what format do you recommend?

Comment: Look at HTML5 "SVG" - a language to draw vector 2D graphics in HTML. Read more at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_svg.asp

Answer (score 1):

The image doesn't look good (looks similar to IE) in FireFox too.
I would suggest not to use HTML to resize image and use some image editor like Photoshop or GIMP(free) or even MS-Paint to create a smaller image to use in your website. The purpose is the website should look good. This will solve your issue effectively.